# PHP htmlspecialchars() ignoring newline and tabs from the text which I get from database

Tags: php, mysql

My code:-

```
$Question=htmlspecialchars($row[2], ENT_QUOTES);//$row[2] has text in format
echo "$Question";
```

Above code is ignoring newline. and printing all text in one line.

Comment: There's no entity for newline. Use `nl2br()` to convert newlines to `<br>` tags, or echo it in a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP htmlspecialchars do not convert newline or tabs, you can read the [htmlspecialchars documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

In html, text is trimmed. So if you want newlines, spaces and tabs to be shown, you need to use the [preformatted text tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

```
echo "<pre>$Question</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you This is really helpful for me.